# basic python: how do i create the next item on the list based on previous item?

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a simpler way to write the following code?  Currently the code is taking forever to run, which is strange.  Something is wrong with it...seems way too complicated for the objective.  I also get a `SettingWithCopyWarning` notice that says:

> a value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

The objective is:  I have four time series/columns - `a, b, c and d`, where `d` is the output column that needs to be populated.

1. if `a` is larger than `b`, then return 1 in column `d`,
2. if `a` is below `c`, then return 0 in column `d`,
3. and if `a` is between `b` and `c`, then return the previous item in column `d`.

Notice that this last `if` statement references the previous item in column d.

```
data['d']=1
data['previous_d']=1

for i in range (len(data.a)):
    data.previous_d.iloc[i]=data.d.iloc[i-1]
    data.stance.iloc[i] = np.where((data.a.iloc[i]> data.b.iloc[i]),1,np.where((data.a.iloc[i]< data.c.iloc[i]),0,data.previous_d.iloc[i]))
```

Comment: if the code works, everything fine. No need to do code refactoring

Comment: @Rockbar Why not? But question must be asked in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What if `a > b and a < c`?

Comment: just edited my question to be more clear.  THANK YOU FOR THE HELP.

Comment: b is always larger than c...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some Boolean indexing will work

```
data.loc[data.a> data.b,'d'] = 1
data.loc[data.a < data.c,'d'] = 0
data.loc[(data.a < data.b) & (data.a > data.c),'d'] = data.d.shift(1)
```

Or if the third conditions means that every thing between unfilled numbers is filled from the last populated value, use

```
data.d.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
```

instead of the last line